# How do i animate in python turtle? (Bycicle)

Tags: python, python-turtle

I a currently trying to animate this bicycle in PYTHON TURTLE.  I am struggling if anyone can teach me how to animate it with code, I will be grateful for that. I am adding more details as I am only trying to make the bicycle wheels move from one place to another like the bicycle wheels animation and the bicycle moves while the wheels are also moving thank you a lot!

```
import turtle
turtle.delay(10)
turtle.pensize(20)

# Move the turtle to the right position of the left tyre
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-87.5, -50)
turtle.setheading(90)

# Draw the left tyre
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(62.5)
turtle.end_fill()

# Move the turtle to the right position of the right tyre
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(212.5, -50)
turtle.setheading(90)

# Draw the right tyre
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(62.5)
turtle.end_fill()

# Draw the handle
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(137.5, 0)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setposition(75, 150)

# Draw the straight part of the handle
turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.setposition(125, 150)

# Draw the circular part of the handle
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(125, 100)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(25, 180)

# Draw the seat tube
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(12.5, -50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setposition(-62.5, 137.5)

# Draw the saddle
turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.setposition(-100, 137.5)

# Draw the top tube
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(100, 75)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setposition(-37.5, 75)

# Draw the down tube
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(100, 75)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setposition(12.5, -50)

# Draw the seat stay
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-37.5, 75)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setposition(-150, -50)

# Draw the chain stay
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(12.5, -50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setposition(-150, -50)
```

Comment: This link should help : it shows an animation of a circle with turtle module : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/draw-moving-object-using-turtle-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I came with for the animation of two wheels and some kind of handlebar :

```py
import turtle
import time

def moving_wheel(turtle):
    turtle.fillcolor('orange')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(20)
    turtle.end_fill()

def moving_handle(turtle):
    pos = turtle.pos()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(70)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(110)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(pos)
    turtle.right(210)
    
    turtle.pendown()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(600, 600)
    screen.bgcolor('green')
    screen.tracer(0)

    t1 = turtle.Turtle()
    t2 = turtle.Turtle()
    t3 = turtle.Turtle()

    # set a turtle object color
    t1.color('red')
    t2.color('red')
    t3.color('red')

    # set turtle object speed
    t1.speed(0)
    t2.speed(0)
    t3.speed(0)

    t1.width(2)
    t2.width(2)
    t3.width(1.5)

    t1.hideturtle()
    t2.hideturtle()
    t3.hideturtle()

    # turtle object in air
    t1.penup()
    t2.penup()
    t3.penup()

    # set initial position
    t1.goto(-250, 0)
    t2.goto(-150,0)
    t3.goto(-150,20)
    t3.pendown()


    # move turtle object to surface
    t1.pendown()
    t2.pendown()

    # infinite loop
    while True:

        # clear turtle work
        t1.clear()
        t2.clear()
        t3.clear()

        # call function to draw ball
        moving_wheel(t1)
        moving_wheel(t2)
        moving_handle(t3)

        # update screen
        screen.update()

        # forward motion by turtle object
        t1.forward(0.1)
        t2.forward(0.1)
        t3.forward(0.1)
```

You can modify the code for the handle part, I'm not an artist haha